# Regular Expression or Library for validating the Built in XSD types?

Tags: java, xml, regex, xsd

The XML Schema spec defines a lot of built in data types http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes is there Java library which can answer questions about weather a value is a a specific data type.  Something along the lines.

```
if(XSDValidator.isXSDDate("2012-06-12") == false) { 
    // return error 
}
```

***Update:***
The use case for this is not in the context of XML but rather in situations where I have a a string that I want to conform to a one of the XSD types and I want a standard way to check that it conforms. For example the string could be a value I extract from an incoming JSON request, or from a URL or any other place ... etc.

Comment: I don't think anything like that is available. Most XML parsing libraries will try to parse the whole thing and chuck errors if anything goes wrong. Looks like you'll have to make one yourself. There's a fairly limited amount of data types, and possibly an even smaller number of them if you consider only the ones you're interested in.

Comment: I'd be surprised if Xerces J didn't give you this kind of interface (but you may have to read past a lot of descriptions of how to process full XML documents).  And if you want to do it with regexes, the XSD 1.1 spec has regexes for the built-ins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are some classes available in the JDK/JRE that you could potentially use:

**javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar**

For date/time types you could use `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` which is included as part of the JDK/JRE since Java SE 5.

```
DatatypeFactory df = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = df.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2012-06-18");
return DatatypeConstants.DATE.equals(xgc.getXMLSchemaType());
```

**javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConveter**

There is also `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConveter` that will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` for bad values:

```
DatatypeConverter.parseDate("2012-06-18");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that uses the [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/) parser/validator. It uses `.impl` classes however. Those are not part of the public API and subject to change. But if you stick to a certain version, you should be fine.

First, the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is a small program that works like you described:

```
import org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.InvalidDatatypeValueException;
import org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs.DateDV;

public class XSDValidator {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isXSDDate("2012-09-18"));
        System.out.println(isXSDDate("Hello World"));
    }

    private static boolean isXSDDate(final String string) {
        try {
            new DateDV().getActualValue(string);
            return true;
        } catch(final InvalidDatatypeValueException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

All you have to do yourself is to create methods for each of the data types. You should be able to find all the required classes in the [org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.xs](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/impl/dv/xs/package-summary.html) package.

Again, this is kind of abusing the Xerces library, as these classes are not part of the public API. So if you find another, cleaner solution, let us know.